# ¿Como enviar mensajes de error o de info a la vista con ModelState?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo el siguiente formulario con `Ajax.BeginForm`

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("MiAccion", "MiController", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, new AjaxOptions
    {
        OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
        OnFailure = "OnFailure"
    }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="SigninX-Main-Title">
            <h1>Iniciar Sesión</h1>
            <p>Ir a Sucursal virtual</p>
        </div>
        <div class="SigninX-Main-Field u-pad-T-1">
            <div class="SigninX-Main-Field-Inputs u-pad-T-1">
                <div class="col-12 u-no-pad">
                    <div class="input-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "validate" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "red-text" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field">
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "validate" })
                        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "red-text" })
                    </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Siguiente</button>

                    </div>
                }
```

Mi controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MiAccion(LoginViewModel model)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Mi Titulo";

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       return View(model);

    if (model.UserName == "miusuario")
        ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Ups, ocurrio un error");

    return View();
}
```

Pero no me imprime el mensaje de error en mi vista. Estuve leyendo que se debe a las funciones del evento `OnSucces` y `OnFailure` de `Ajax.BeginForm. ¿Alguien sabe como poder manejar esto para que me aparezca el mensaje en la vista?

Cabe mencionar que si el formulario se cambia a uno normal (sin ajax) funciona.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo único que te falta es poner la siguiente línea de código en la vista junto a `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Con eso debería funcionar.

Comment: No falta, esta puesto en el código. `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`